# jQuery find using function as argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, traversal

I have always missed a traverse function in jQuery, and I thinking that there might be one but I missed it. Say we have the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Doe</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, if I want to add an active class to the anchor I clicked and deactivate the others, I would normally have to do this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active')
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .find('a.active')
        .removeClass('active');
});
```

But what I want is to do is this:

```
var relation = function() {
    return $(this).parent().siblings().find('a.active');
};

$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').find(relation).removeClass('active');
});
```

See the difference? Now, `find` doesn’t take a function as argument, so I wrote something like this:

```
$.fn.traverse = function(fn) {
    return $.isFunction(fn) ? fn.call(this) : this;
};
```

As an example, this simple method makes it possible to create an "activate" plugin that lets the author specify the relationship to the deactivations:

```
$.fn.activate = function(fn) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').traverse(fn || function() {
            return $(this).siblings();
        }).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

And use it like this:

```
$('a').activate(function() {
    return $(this).parent().siblings().find('.active');
});

// or

$('a').activate(function() {
    return $(this).closest('ul').find('a.active').not(this);
});

// or

$('li').activate();
```

This will do the job. But my question is that there really should be something like this included in jQuery somewhere, no? I was looking at `.map` but it doesn’t work that way.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: The find example makes no sense, did you mean removeClass?

Comment: I edited with an implementation example. The idea is to be able to traverse through an anonymous function instead of just selectors or traverse methods.

Comment: `$("ul a").each(function() { doStuff(this); });` ?

Comment: @Laoujin yes except that `each` returns the same collection.

Comment: This seems like a solution in search of a problem. The way you describe as the normal way looks much clearer to me than your new way, especially if you have a well-structured DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern in jQuery is:

- find the elements you want to change, then
- call a method to do something to them.

There are many other ways you *could* do things, but this way works fine and it is the way the library is designed to work. I would need a compelling reason to depart from that. (Not just “But I want to do it this way.”)

I would write it like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Chaining is overrated. If you want to do two things, try writing two lines of code. You might like it!

Comment: There are a lot of traverse methods, such as `.parent()`, and most of them can take a selector for further filtering. But no traverse method takes a function, even though they added functions as arguments for many other things, such as `.css()`. That was my point.

Comment: I agree, and I’m starting to think that I failed to provide a clear purpose with my question...

Comment: @David I see what you mean. But I still think that’s just because it wouldn’t be useful to take a function there. Any time you write `$(x).traverse(function () { return $(this).PIPELINE(); });` it would be shorter and clearer to just write `$(x).PIPELINE()`.

Comment: How about `$(this).traverse(function() { return hasChildren ? $(this).children() : $(this).parents() ).addClass('foo');` VS `if (hasChildren) { $(this).children().addClass('foo'); } else { $(this).parents().addClass('foo')}`? It would follow the "usual pattern" you describe.

Comment: @David That seems a little contrived, but in that case you’d write `(hasChildren ? $(this).children() : $(this).parents()).addClass('foo');` or better still, use two lines of code: `var targets = hasChildren ? $(this).children() : $(this).parents(); targets.addClass('foo');`